# Disable App Nap

Tags: swift, macos, sleep

I really need to disable App Nap in my OS X application in Swift but I've looked all over the web and can't find an answer. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
let myQueue = OperationQueue()
    let myActivity = ProcessInfo.processInfo.beginActivity(
        options: ProcessInfo.ActivityOptions.userInitiated,
        reason: "Batch processing files")
    myQueue.addOperation(
        {
            // Perform batch processing of files here
            ProcessInfo.processInfo.endActivity(myActivity)
        }
    )
```

Read more about App Nap on Apples reference site [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/power_efficiency_guidelines_osx/PrioritizeWorkAtTheAppLevel.html).

Comment: That is up to you to decide. It depends how you structured your app and, more importantly, *why* you want to disable AppNap.